# Stop flask or gunicorn from printing to the console

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have asked a similar question, to which I have received no help. Essentially I have a flask application running with gunicorn as a wsgi and nginx as a webserver. For some reason when I send a post request via a separate python script (and only this script, regular browser requests don't do this) the server prints the requests headers to the console. The problem with this is, as I have figured out, when I don't have an ssh connection with the server flask/gunicorn (I'm not sure which is actually printing it) doesn't have a console to print to. This results in a 500 internal server error. I obviously can't constantly keep reconnecting to the server every 30 min when the connection closes. I have looked in gunicorns documentation and (through my research) have found no mention of what is causing this. This leads me to believe flask is to blame although I can't be sure. The output looks like this

```
Host: [domain].com
X-Real-Ip: [my ip address]
X-Forwarded-For: [my ip address]
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Connection: close
Content-Length: 18910
User-Agent: python-requests/2.25.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: session=[session cookie]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How exactly are you launching gunicorn?  Nginx might return a 500 error if gunicorn isn't running.  It's not clear from your description, but it sounds like the SSH session you talk about is actually where you're running gunicorn.  You may need to investigate launching gunicorn as a background service, so that it continues running when you log out of SSH?  (Does that match your situation?  Again you're question doesn't make this clear).  This needs more info like basic python code of the server, and nginx/gunicorn config details before anyone can help.

Comment: @v25 gunicorn is running fine even when I close the connection. I can visit it via a web browser and it works just fine, no error. (gunicorn -w 3 app:app)

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing, before sending a request make sure your server is up by making use of **ping**.

If the ping response is successful then make a post request. Otherwise post call will end up with exception, and exception would result in unexpected results in further requests like yours.

Make use of generator in this case as it won't bring trouble in execution of other processes.

If necessary for making periodic requests, you would better prefer the python schedule to run tasks.